# Laravel - How to create controller inside folder app but outside folder http

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel-8 for an application. I have a folder Api inside folder app of Laravel. And i want to create Controller inside folder Web. But when i run command line:

```
php artisan Api/V1/Appraisal/AppraisalGoalsController
```

It create controller inside folder Http/Controllers as default.

So how to do that?

Comment: If you avoid Laravel's structure, there will be a lot of code you'd need to fix additionally. Good location would be `app/Http/Controllers/Api/V1/Appraisal/<AllAppraisalApiControllers>`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a folder in "Http\Controllers" called "Api" and move forward from there?